# Is it possible to generate the wheel lazily?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

On the [The Genuine Sieve of Erastosthenes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) paper, the author uses a wheel of finite size to skip checking multiples of the first N primes on the sieve construction. For example, in order to avoid checking multiples of `2, 3`, you can begin at `5`, and alternately add 2 and 4. This is the `wheel 2` below:

```
-- wheel 0 = ([2],[1])
-- wheel 1 = ([3,2],[2])
-- wheel 2 = ([5,3,2],[2,4]) -- "start at 5, add 2, 4, 2, 4..."
-- wheel 3 = ([7,5,3,2],[4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6])
```

Her wheel is fully generated on the startup of the sieving process. This presents a tradeoff, since larger wheels require more memory. I find the underlying mechanism behind the wheel generation interesting by itself, though. Given its clearly repetitive nature, I wonder if it would be possible to create an "infinite wheel" which, like the sieve, presented itself as a stream? This stream would be, I guess, the limit of the sequence of lists `[1], [2], [2, 4], [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6]...` - and probably work as an implementation of `primes` itself.

Comment: I think the "infinite wheel" is is essentially the sieving process itself.

Comment: From the paper: "*I will leave experimenting with larger wheels and writing code to generate those wheels as a recreational exercise for the reader.*" - well done :-)

Comment: @ErikR are you sure? It looks like a different series [1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6](https://oeis.org/A001223), so it could have different generating characteristics.

Comment: @Viclib `primes = scanl (+) 2 gaps` and `gaps = (zipWith (-) =<< tail) primes`, which is trivial enough to call it an "encoding" of the primes. Constructing the infinite wheel has a lot in common with the sieving process.

Comment: That sequence of lists has no limit ( a limit exists only if they all share a finite prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bakuriu says, the wheel sequence has no limit. There is no such thing as the "infinite wheel", I'll try to demonstrate why.

If we know the first prime numbers p_1,...,p_n, we only need to search the next ones among the numbers that are coprime to them :

```
isCoprime :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
isCoprime ps x = all (\p -> x `mod` p /= 0) ps
```

The set Coprime(p_1,...,p_n) is (p_1...p_n)-periodic (x is inside it if and only if x + p_1...p_n is inside it), so we call it a wheel.

You're asking for the limit of this Coprime set, as we take more and more prime numbers p_i. However, the only number in Coprime(p_1,...,p_n) below p_n is 1. To prove this, observe that a prime factor of such a number would be one of the p_i.

So as the number of primes tends to infinity, Coprime(p_1,...,p_n) leaves a huge empty hole between 1 and p_n. The only limit you can think of is therefore the empty set : there is no infinite wheel.

Comment: I realized there is no infinite well. There is still an infinite list of the concatenation of consecutive wheels, which is this `gaps` as pointed on the comments.

Comment: Why would you concatenate wheel532 and wheel7532 ? It doesn't give you a wheel.

Comment: I was just thinking that if there was a simple way to generate the `gaps` sequence (which is the concatenation of the wheels), then it could give us a new implementation of `primes` itself.

Comment: Can you post a proof that gaps is the concatenation of the wheels ?